# Why did GERTY do this (spoilers)?

Tags: moon-movie

About halfway through [Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_%28film%29), GERTY

> enters a password into the computer Sam is working on, enabling him to view classified video.

Up until that point, GERTY appears to be

> preventing Sam from discovering the truth of his nature.

So, why did GERTY change its mind and decide to help Sam?

Comment: We can't know the AI's motivation, but it seems like by the end of the movie that GERTY is more concerned with keeping Sam alive than it is with keeping the secret...sort of a reverse HAL of you will.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The whole point is that **GERTY isn't HAL**. HAL's primary motivation is the safety of the mission and the safety of the ship, even if that means killing the crew. By comparison, GERTY seems cognisant that without Sam, the mission will fail. That means keeping the current version sane or (when problems occur)...

> killing him and replacing him with another one of the stock of Sam clones.

As Duncan Jones (the Film's Director) said in this press interview, he wanted to subvert the trope of an evil machine intelligence being the film's main villain.

> **Interviewer :** *You talked fairly openly about what many call the twist in the film. For me, though, what was the major surprise was
>   Gerty at the end, that you knocked the idea of what to expect. You
>   seemed to be having a lot of fun playing with the old conventions of
>   the genre?*
>
> **Duncan Jones :** *Absolutely. The more of them we could come up with, the more fun that it was. Gerty and HAL were obviously one
>   reference...All these things that we were trying to do to make people
>   really expect a certain thing and then go in a different direction
>   with it. We tried to do that in a number of different places.*